# Django Admin TabularInline Complaining About Missing Field

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have the following model and TabularInline subclasses:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class SomeModelInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SomeModel

class SomeOtherModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [SomeModelInline]
```

Without explicitly specifying the TabularInline's fields, Django's admin shows the fields "id" and "name". However, when I try and do:

```
class SomeModelInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SomeModel
    fields  ['id','name']
```

Django throws the ImproperlyConfigured exception:

```
'SomeModelInline.fields' refers to field 'id' that is missing from the form.
```

What's going on here? Why can't I explicitly specify the id, even though Django's clearly capable of accessing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ids are non-editable, by default inline shows the editable fields, but you can show the non-editable fields as well

From [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields)

> fields can contain values defined in ModelAdmin.readonly_fields to be
>   displayed as read-only.

So first add 'id' to readonly_fields, then add it to fields

Comment: That's not really what I asked, but it does allow me to work around the problem.